# what's the best practice to repeat Android Volley requests automatically?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have made ListView populated by Volley JsonObjectRequest and setShouldCache to false..
Now I want to re-populate it every 5 mins, so what's the best practice to do that ??

I thought about making Handler that manages runnable adding requests to the queue every 5 mins..

#### UPDATE 1

I have Volley JsonObjectRequest like this

```
    jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "Place Holder for URL ",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jObj) {
                        // Some Processing Here
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            // Some Processing Here

        }
    });
    jsObjRequest.setShouldCache(false);
```

Then I add it to the RequestQueue

```
              addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Volley only executes it one time.

My question is if there any method using Volley to repeat it every specific period of time.

Comment: I also have a problem and my problem was solved with the `handler.postDelayed(userUpdater, USERS_UPDATE_INTERVAL);`, but high server load and increases server users will not work. No any idea?

Comment: @ImanMarashi I have in my mind two solutions. first use load balancing on the server. second . let the alarm periodic time be dynamically generated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

I found the solution to use IntentService and AlarmManager to repeat the requested task like this

```
    // The IntentService
    public class AnnouncementIntentService extends IntentService {

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    CustomRequestQueue.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}}
```

```
// The Alarm Manager Code
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, AnnouncementIntentService.class);
    PendingIntent pinIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, i,
            0);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000L, pinIntent);
```